# Is there energy stored when iron is magnetized?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential-energy, magnetic-moment

When a piece of iron is magnetized, and the domains are aligned,
Is there energy stored? If so, how much energy is stored?
If there is an attraction between that same iron and the source of the exterior magnetic field,where work is done, and there is energy that is transferred. Is the energy equal to that of which is stored in the alignment of the domains?

**And how much energy is stored or needed to align the domains?**

Comment: Yes. Energy is stored. A compact answer is here http://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=17858 .

Comment: @annav I've read the source, very useful thank you! However, Is the energy stored(from the energy density) in the field equal to the energy applied to align the domains? And is it equal to the energy needed to demagnetize the domains? Example, say a magnet's magnetic field has stored energy of 50J, that means it can do work that is equal to 50J on ferromagnets, in order to demagnetize the magnet do we apply the same amount? Or even demagnetize the  ferromagnets that are attracted to the magnet?

Comment: Energy is conserved, therefore atleast that much energy must be supplied as the one that exists in the ordered domains, but in general there is always some loss in recovering stored energy, to heat , to radiation or to motion, depending on the method of recovery.

Comment: @annav I agree. However, is the total energy of the system composed of multiple sources? For example: The energy that is required to magnetize the ferromagnet & The energy stored in the field to do work on other ferromagnetic objects like attracting them etc... = Net total energy stored? Because it seems the magnetization by itself is a process that requires energy. And the phenomenon of attraction also requires energy of its own. So I assume the total energy conserved is composed of E1 + E2 + E3 = E total.

Comment: @annav For some reason I believe that the energy required to magnetized a soft iron ferromagnet is not equal to the amount of energy applied to attract it by an exterior magnetic field. So that's why I assume the energy is a net total of adding them up or something like that.

Comment: Hmm. Physics is not a matter of beliefs. a permanent magnet and an electromagnet do not differ if they have the same field around them. A piece of a ferromagnetic material to become permanently at high level  magnetized needs to stay in a magnetic field a long time, otherwise the effect is transient. Long time means more energy spent ( could be measured with an electromagnet I guess).See here about hysteresis etc here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/magperm.html

Comment: @annav Sorry for not clearing this out earlier but that was not my question. The kind of ferromagnet that is used is a soft iron kind, that has a low coercivity force. So the work/energy needed to magnetize it is very low. I was only wondering the amount of work/energy that is needed to demagnetize a soft iron or change its domains from an exterior field(B), and I assume it should be low as well. Since it has a very low coercive force.

Comment: @annav My argument is, the amount of energy to magnetize the soft iron, is NOT EQUAL, to the amount of energy the field applies to attract the soft iron. It should be less. Magnetization and Attraction are two different effects aren't they? Those two effects have different values of energy depending on the system. That is not what I "believe" it's what I observed, and would like to share to be analyzed.

Comment: It seems to me that analyzing what goes on with magnetization domains is still a matter of research. You do not give observations in your question and how you measured the energy? From the links I have provided it seems that much smaller magnetic fields than the intrinsic domain field manage to orient the domains. I do not have the tools to estimate whether the energy supplied is bigger or smaller than the energy available once the large scale field appears.

Comment: @annav  Here is my first source that describes the energy required to magnetize soft iron ferromagnets:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetocrystalline_anisotropy   -- Under Particle Relevance.  Also,from that I concluded how the energy used to attract the same soft iron is not equal to it's magnetization. So, attraction's energy is equal to magnetization's energy. This however, is an assumption based on a simple experiment and the previous source,I will bring more data to support it.Don't you think magnetization has a different value to attraction?Or you believe they are all the same E values?

Comment: Yes, I can intuit that to magnetize something you have to spend much more energy than the energy given up by the magnet in attracting something. I cannot calculate it though and even from the links you give the calculations of these quantities are still a matter of research because it involves crystal structures and bindings. I think I will stop commenting here because this is the extent of my knowledge on this subject. I do not base my physics knowledge on beliefs  ( except on basic axioms until falsified) and even my  intuitions have to be backed up by numbers.

Comment: Thank you for everything,it depends what that "something" is, weather its a hard/soft iron then you can determine the amount of energy needed. but I think you did not notice my point of "Soft irons" and their low coercivity, it would require  low amount of energy/work to align or randomize the domains. "To magnetize **something**" it depends what kind of "something it is, soft/hard iron. Thus I "assume" the work to magnetize it or demagnetize it is fairly low. Based on the link I provided.

Comment: look up the phenomenon of hysteresis. any material with nonzero coercivity and saturation remanence cannot be magnetized or demagnetized without losses

Answer (score 2):

I believe the term you're looking for is "Magnetostatic Energy".  [Magnetostatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics) is the field that studies static (constant) magnetic fields, much like electrostatics.

For a uniform material the magnetostatic stored potential energy is:

$$E_{\mathrm{ms}} = \frac{1}{2}\mu_0 \int_V \mathbf{M} \cdot \mathbf{H}_{\mathrm{ms}} d^3 r$$

You can find a [full derivation here](http://www.cwscholz.net/projects/da/node9.html).  The [Wikipedia article on magnetic domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain) also covers a lot of details about the field energy.

Comment: For more details, see [IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON MAGNETICS, VOL 27, NO 4, JULY 1991; Magnetostatic Energy Calculations; Amikam Aharoni, Fellow, IEEE](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/20/3181/00102925.pdf?arnumber=102925)

Answer (score 0):

Well you probably should check on this, but if I am not mistaken, the (ferro) magnetized state is actually a lower energy state.   I believe there is a process called "adiabatic demagnetization" that is actually used to reach lower cryogenic temperatures.  Well like I said; check it out.

Comment: "A bulk piece of ferromagnetic material in its lowest energy state has little or no external magnetic field. The material is said to be "unmagnetized"." - Wikipedia

Comment: This is confusing. There is the "Ex" exchange energy that is lowest when the domains all point in the same direction... "It is lowest when the dipoles are all pointed in the same direction, so it is responsible for magnetization of magnetic materials. When two domains with different directions of magnetization are next to each other, at the domain wall between them magnetic dipoles pointed in different directions lie next to each other, increasing this energy. This additional exchange energy is proportional to the total area of the domain walls." - Wikipeida

Comment: Sounds confusing to me too V-XCIX.   Seems like my memory could have it backwards.   I don't do Wikipedia; but if you like it, check out the adiabatic demagnetization angle.  But Anna usually has it straight.

Comment: this is another question, i.e., "what is the minimum energy state of ferromangetic materials .From this link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/ferro.html it seems that the theoretical formulation of how domains under the influence of an external field reorient themselves is still under investigation. The statement about random orientation having the minimum energy is correct: think of two permanent magnets, it takes energy to keep them parallel, they tend to end up north to south, no? The wiki article goes on to talk about stable secondary minima due to crystal structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is it store "lower entropy state", not the energy

Comment: Hi Thaina, can you please expand and clarify your answer?

Comment: Magnet is ordered atom of iron, lower entropy means lower chaotic. It relate to energy of the system that lower entropy can be converted to energy. Like you have water store in high ground